# Certbot: Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore. Certbot will no longer receive updates

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, certbot

How do I manually update the certificates that Certbot would normally update? I did not change anything in my system so I am assuming it is because I have CentOS 6. I also have Apache. How do I update the certificates manually?

```
SUBJECT: Cron <root@ip-99-99-99-99> scl enable python27 "/root/certbot-auto renew --quiet"
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot will no longer receive updates.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.
```

Comment: Your going to have to update the OS sooner or later. Sooner fixes this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I have some Rhel6 systems doing the same thing.  As far as I can tell if certbot is already installed then it will continue to renew certs and you can order new ones.  However, certbot itself will not be getting updated so at some point it may stop working even for systems with it installed.    See this link for a full explanation:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-auto-deprecated-explanation-and-solutions/139821

Comment: It suggested I install `snap` and I got as far as https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-centos, but when I tried to install it `sudo yum install snapd`, I got the error `No package snapd available`. They only had instructions for CentOS 7 and 8. I have 6 and tried with the 7 instructions.

Comment: I tried `pip install certbot` but got the errors: `DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).` and `ERROR: ConfigArgParse requires Python '>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*' but the running Python is 3.4.10`.

Comment: I tried `yum install python-pip` to get `pip 7.1.0 (python 2.6)` and tried `pip install certbot` but got the error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-imH4p0/cryptography`.

Comment: I tried to upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` but got `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.`

Comment: I finally got the right pip with `scl enable python27 "python get-pip.py"` and tried `scl enable python27 "pip install certbot"` but it gave the error `ERROR: josepy 1.6.0 has requirement setuptools>=1.0, but you'll have setuptools 0.9.8 which is incompatible.` and `WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 20.3.4 is available.`. This answer just doesn't work.